# Add custom layout to ConstraintLayout programmatically

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout, layout-inflater

Good day everyone.
I'm trying to a layout to a `ConstraintLayout` in a `for-loop`.

The layout is decalred as follows:

```
public class SingleMeal extends ConstraintLayout {
    private TextView food_id;
    private ImageButton spacer_minus;
    private ImageButton spacer_plus;
    private TextView food_quantity;

    public SingleMeal(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    private void init(){
        inflate(getContext(), R.layout.activity_single_meal, this);
        this.food_id = findViewById(R.id.food_id);
        this.spacer_minus = findViewById(R.id.spacer_minus);
        this.spacer_plus = findViewById(R.id.spacer_plus);
        this.food_quantity = findViewById(R.id.food_quantity);
    }

    public void setFood_id(String food_id) {
        this.food_id.setText(food_id);
    }

    public TextView getFood_quantity() {
        return food_quantity;
    }

    public ImageButton getSpacer_minus() {
        return spacer_minus;
    }

    public ImageButton getSpacer_plus() {
        return spacer_plus;
    }
}
```

The xml of the layout is as follows:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".selectMeals.SingleMeal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/food_id"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/edit_text_height"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/medium_space"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_size"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_food_quantity"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/medium_space"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/spacer_minus"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/plus_minus"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/plus_minus"
            android:background="@drawable/minus"
            android:contentDescription="@string/spacer"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/food_quantity"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/info_quantity"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/edit_text_height"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="0"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/spacer_plus"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/plus_minus"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/plus_minus"
            android:background="@drawable/plus"
            android:contentDescription="@string/spacer"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

On the main activity I'm creating a new `SingleMeal` object, and populate it it's methods.

```
ConstraintLayout previousCourse = null;
for (Course course : meal.getCourses()) {
    final SingleMeal food_container = new SingleMeal(this);

    food_container.setId(View.generateViewId());
    food_container.setFood_id(course.getName());
    final TextView food_quantity = food_container.getFood_quantity();

    ImageButton minus = food_container.getSpacer_minus();
    minus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String foodQuantity = food_quantity.getText().toString();
            int foodQuantityInt = Integer.parseInt(foodQuantity) > 0 ? Integer.parseInt(foodQuantity) - 1 : Integer.parseInt(foodQuantity);
            food_quantity.setText(String.valueOf(foodQuantityInt));
        }
    });

    ImageButton plus = food_container.getSpacer_plus();
    plus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String foodQuantity = food_quantity.getText().toString();
            int foodQuantityInt = Integer.parseInt(foodQuantity) + 1;
            food_quantity.setText(String.valueOf(foodQuantityInt));
        }
    });

    lunchCountainer.addView(food_container);

    ConstraintSet constraintSet = new ConstraintSet();
    constraintSet.clone(lunchCountainer);
    if (previousCourse == null)
        constraintSet.connect(food_container.getId(), ConstraintSet.TOP , findViewById(R.id.txt_menu_date).getId(), ConstraintSet.BOTTOM,0);
    else
        constraintSet.connect(food_container.getId(), ConstraintSet.TOP , previousCourse.getId(), ConstraintSet.BOTTOM,0);
    constraintSet.applyTo(lunchCountainer);

    previousCourse = food_container;
}
```

I'm probably doing something very wrong as it goes trough the loop without any error, but it is not showing anything in the end.

The `lunchContainer` as previously said is a ConstraintLayout (inside a `ScrollView`):

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
android:id="@+id/lunch_container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
android:isScrollContainer="true"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay"
android:scrollbars="vertical" />
```

Any idea?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you should be looking at the `RecyclerView` instead of `ConstraintLayout` for your case...

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you don't want a ConstraintLayout here, if you are stacking the items vertically I would suggest a LinearLayout set to Vertical.

Set the width of each item to MATCH_PARENT, then set the layout weight to be the same on each item, but make sure the height is set to WRAP_CONTENT so the sizes are the same for each item.

Not 100% sure this will work but this is the way to do it.

Or you could use a ListView, with your items within that, this will also handle scrolling etc for you.

Either option will work for you.